# Getting Application-defined or object-defined error on protecting the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Below code is working fine, however when I protect the excel sheet, I receive the following error message: *ERROR Message: "Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error"*

When I debug, the below code was highlighted

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
 Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="AJ"
```

Can you please help me on this.

```
With Range("A2:A3").Validation
 .Delete
 .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
 Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="AJ"
 .IgnoreBlank = True
 .InCellDropdown = True
 .InputTitle = ""
 .ErrorTitle = ""
 .InputMessage = ""
 .ErrorMessage = ""
 .ShowInput = True
 .ShowError = True
End With
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to make changes to a protected sheet, in the code you will have to unprotect it first using the [worksheet.unprotect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-unprotect-method-excel)

Once you are done making the change then call the [worksheet.protect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel) to lock it back up again.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. This worked.